# Image of a set under function

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having a trouble in solving this problem in Complex analysis:

So, we have the unit disc $D = \{x \in \mathbb{C} \mid |x| < 1\}$ and a complex function defined by:

$$\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{2 z}{(z+1)^2}$$

Determine $f(D).$

Comment: Here $f$ is not defined at $-1$ which is a point in $D$.

Comment: So take with a strong inequality, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

So, a solution is easy:

Take a parametrization of a unit circle, $e^{it}$, if it is not $-1$. Then we will gain real numbers, it is not hard to check. Thus our image is everything ($\mathbb{C}$) but real line.